# Wordpress Pre-loader

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Buenas mi gente una duda, ¿como puedo crear un custom preloader en wordpress? porque veo que los plugins que existen solamente hacen algo basico pero quiero añadirle mas animacion.

Comment: Tienes que intentarlo cuando tengas algo comenzado y tengas un problema con gusto podemos ayudarte. Lo único que se me ocurre si quieres algo realmente personalizado es que agregues un script que lo muestre

Comment: el "mas animación" es para el preloader o para el contenido?

Comment: la animacion es para ambos